# How to prove by coinduction?

Tags: coinduction

Previously, I've asked [a question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124640/when-can-the-coinduction-hypothesis-be-used) about coinduction. That gave me a lot of useful high-level insights on what coinduction provides, and what are the usefulness of coinductive proofs.

This question is about walking through an example in more detail. The example is based on this other question ["What is coinduction?"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/525/what-is-coinduction). I'll copy some Coq code from that question over here.

First, we have a colist.

```
CoInductive colist (A:Set) : Set :=
  | conil : colist A
  | cocons : A -> colist A -> colist A.
```

Then we have the `from` function.

```
CoFixpoint from (n:Nat) : colist Nat := cocons n (from (1 + n)).
```

Then we have a proposition about infinite colists.

```
CoInductive Infinite A : colist A -> Prop :=
  | Inf : forall x l, Infinite l -> Infinite (cocons x l).
```

I'd like to prove `forall n, Infinite from n`.

Using The coinduction principle [1] says to prove $X \subseteq vF$, it suffices to show $X \subseteq F X$.

Questions: What is $X$, $F$, $vF$, the theorem $X \subseteq vF$, and the proof obligation $X \subseteq F X$ stated in terms of `from` and `Infinite`?

---

Below is my attempt to answer these questions.

$X$ is the set of colists "generated by" `from`. Maybe it looks like this?

```
x: Nat    from (x+1): ColistGeneratedByFrom
-------------------------------------------
cocons x from (x+1): ColistGeneratedByFrom
```

$F$ is applying `Infinite` once.

```
F(X) = {cocons x l | x: Nat, l: X}
```

$vF$ is the set of colists "generated by" Infinite. Maybe it looks like this?

```
y: Nat   l: ColistGeneratedByInfinite
-------------------------------------
cocons y l: ColistGeneratedByInfinite
```

The theorem $X \subseteq vF$ is proving that `ColistGeneratedByFrom` $\subseteq$ `ColistGeneratedByInfinite`. That any colist generated by `from` has the property `Infinite`.

The proof obligation $X \subseteq F X$ says that we only need to show that a colist generated by `from` is "survives" applying `Infinite` once.

From [1], I think that I would need to show something like.

```
forall n: Nat,
  exists m: ColistGeneratedByFrom,
    x: ColistGeneratedByFrom => x = cocons n m
```

But I'm confused how does $F$ lead to this principle that uses `exists`.

I would have simply tried to applied $F$ and get something like

```
forall n: Nat,
  x: ColistGeneratedByFrom => cocons n x: ColistGeneratedByFrom
```

which I'm not sure can be proven.

Where is my understanding correct / incorrect?

Apologies if I'm mixing notations.

[1] [Programming = proving? The Curry-Howard correspondence today](https://xavierleroy.org/CdF/2018-2019/9.pdf)

Comment: I think this question may be better asked on [proofassistants.SE]. As always, please read their FAQ first.